# edit config.xml of notepad++ - c# plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, notepad++

I am building a new notepad++ plugin in c#.I want two forms. 1 down and 1 on the right side.
I did everything through code, but config.xml of Notepad++ is making the form only in 1 location.
if i manually delete config.xml (or edit config.xml),my plugin will work properly.But is there any way to send message to config.xml and make changes.I know this is some how possible,because there is a plugin called "AnalysePlugin" in which two forms are possible.

Could someOne please help me?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What are you trying to do and what is (or is not) happening? I think you need to explain your problem in much more detail.

Comment: Plugin is such a way that 1 windows form should be on down of notepad++ screen and one form should be on the right side of the screen.
I am managing it using `_nppTbData.uMask = NppTbMsg.DWS_DF_CONT_BOTTOM | NppTbMsg.DWS_ICONTAB | NppTbMsg.DWS_ICONBAR;`.it will fix the form to bottom .Similarly for right too.
But config fille of Notepad++ is somehow not getting edited with these details.So both the forms appear 1 side. If i manually delete config file and run the plugin,it will work perfectly.Hope the Question is clear now